# Finding referencing variables on Cloud formation template Fn:ImportValue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have come across one of our existing AWS Infra  CF templates and I found below snippet

```
 "SubnetId" : { "Fn::ImportValue" : "hw-const-GreenBSubnet" },
        "SecurityGroupIds": [
          { "Fn::ImportValue" : "hw-const-InfraSg" },
          { "Fn::ImportValue" : "hw-const-HttpsAllSg" },
```

I undestand the variable hw-const-InfraSg is export of some other stack output after reading through documentation, but how can i find what is the value of vaiable hw-const-InfraSg if i don't know the stack which created it.

does these variables can be configured some where else, please enlighten.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways. You could use CLI to [list existing exports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-exports.html):

```
aws cloudformation list-exports
```

or you could go to CloudFormation console. In the console there is dedicated menu `Exports` that lists and allow you to search through all exports with their values:

[image]

Comment: Thank you this helps.